# Подключить шрифты, чтобы работали на IE

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Подключал шрифты несколькими способами(приведу ниже). Но проблема в том, что либо работает везде, кроме IE, либо только на нем. Подскажите, как подключить все файлы шрифта(чтобы адекватно отображалось на всех браузерах).
Мои попытки(во 2-м и 3-м действовало лишь на латинницу, кириллица не реагировала):

```
@font-face {
 font-family: ChinaCyr;
 src: url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.eot),
 url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.ttf),
 url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.svg),
 url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.woff),
 url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.woff2);}

@font-face {
font-family: 'ChinaCyr';
src: url('font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.ttf')  format('truetype'),
url('font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.eot?') format('eot'),
url('font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.woff') format('woff'),
url('font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.ttf')  format('truetype'),
url('font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.svg') format('svg');}
```

```css
@font-face {
 font-family:ChinaCyr;
 src:url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.eot);
 src:url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.eot?#iefix)format("embedded-opentype"),
 url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.woff)format("woff"),
 url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.ttf)format("truetype"),
 url(font-awesome/font/ChinaCyr.svg#fonts)format("svg");
}
```

Ну или подскажите, как 3-й вариант подвязать еще и на кириллицу.
 Заранее спасибо.

Comment: было бы неплохо взглянуть на лицензирование конкретных шрифтов (можно посмотреть в свойствах файла ttf), ибо не каждый шрифт можно юзать в общем доступе, а IE очень любит обрезать шрифты которые только для личного использования

Comment: В свойствах внедрение шрифта - ограниченное. 
Но если его подключать в гордом одиночестве, то тогда он работает без проблем. 
Меня интересует, правильно ли я пытаюсь впихнуть несколько файлов в одну font-family???

Comment: Последний вариант у вас вполне работоспособный

Comment: Я облазил кучу сайтов. И вроде должно работать, но почему-то не хочет(именно на IE).

Comment: На IE не работает из-за лецинзирования

Answer (score 2):

Подключение шрифта

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Использование

```
body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Должно бы сработать, но к сожалению...

Comment: @DaVinchi А чего именно не работает? Шрифты вообще не подгружаются, даже латиница?